# Printf formatting an integer to have a maximum and minimum of 2 digits displayed

Tags: c, format, printf

In one of my assignments, one line is required to `printf` "My friend is __ years old" where the empty space must contain no more and no less than 2 digits from an integer but no matter what I try, nothing is working...

Here is my code:

```
int age = 22332;

printf("My friend is %2.2i years old.",age);
```

Yet the output ends up being

> My friend is 22332 years old.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What output do you expect for the given age?  You could print `age % 100` to print a 2-digit number between `00` and `99`, for example.  Centenarians get upset by this sort of treatment, though.

Comment: Cut off an integer does not mean anything. It is not a precision control in the aspect of floating number

Answer (score 3):

The 1<sup>st</sup> `"2"` is the *width*.  It directs `"%2.2i"` to print with a *minimum* of 2 *characters*<sup>1</sup>, padding with spaces as needed.
The 2<sup>nd</sup> `"2"` is the *precision*.  It directs `"%2.2i"` to print at least 2 *digits*.

To "have a ... minimum of 2 *digits*", use `"%.2i"`

To "have a maximum ... of 2 *digits*", insure the value is in the range [-99...99].  Example, use `age % 100`

```
printf("My friend is %.2i years old.",age%100);
```

---

Folks over age 99 [Jeanne Calment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_verified_oldest_people), [Methuselah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah), [Imhotep](https://www.toptenz.net/top-10-fictional-characters-who-lived-over-a-thousand-years.php) will print a truncated year.[@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897509/printf-formatting-an-integer-to-have-a-maximum-and-minimum-of-2-digits-displayed/54897891#comment96563723_54897509)

---

<sup>1</sup> "*minimum* of 2 *characters*" includes a potential sign character.

Comment: The '%' technique is really useful with the latest version of GCC (12.1) as it analyses the potential max width of your ints and produces warnings if the buffer could overflow.

Using the '%' allows the compiler know the true max value contained within the int. It was the only way I could remove the warnings from my code without increasing the buffer size to value larger than would really be required.

Comment: @SimonAlfie Agreed.   Also when the `int` value is non-negative, using `printf("My friend is %.2u years old.",age%100u);` is useful to insure a range of  [0...99] as compiler analysis might conclude  `int_age%100` could  take up to 3 characters whereas  `int_age%100u`  takes up to 2.

Answer (score 0):

For the `%i` format specifier, the digit before the decimal specifies the minimum field width, which is the number of spaces the value will take up, and the number after the decimal is the minimum number of digits to display, meaning that the result would be left padded with zeros if too short.

You can't display less digits than is needed to print the number for an integer.  Only for floating point types can you display less digits.

Comment: So does that mean its impossible for me to limit the max number of output digits from an int, implying that what the lab is asking is impossible?

Comment: @ChaseAllen Perhaps you should limit the input to numbers from 0 to 99.

Comment: Well the instructions say to use 22 as my int value and to format the printf statement so that only 2 digits are output... I assumed that meant to limit its min and max to 2... what would you recommend I do? (I used a different int larger than 22 to test to see if my formatting was working btw hence the 2232)

Comment: @ChaseAllen How would you expect such a value to be displayed?

Comment: It says the output should be “My friend is 22 years old” which I can do no problem but it’s the part where it says to format the printf to only display 2 digits is what confuses me...

Comment: @ChaseAllen It sounds like there's an implicit assumption that the value will be less that 100.  If I asked you to write, on paper, the number 2322 using only 2 digits, how would you do it?  You can't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the *minimum* number of digits output, you can use a length specifier like `%.2d`. However, you may not limit the *maximum* number of digits output.

What you can do instead is limit the `int` value before the call:

```
#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

printf("My friend is %.2d years old.\n", min(age, 99));
```